# C Compile-Time assert on const array of function pointers

Tags: c, constants, function-pointers, assert

I have this const array of function pointers:

```
const callback_t callbacks[] =
{
    func1,
    func2,
    func3,
    func4,
    func5
};
```

and I would like to add C Compile-Time assert to ensure that func1 is placed first within the array.
Something like that:

```
C_ASSERT(callbacks[0] == func1);
```

after pre-preocessor stage this is expanded to:

```
extern char __C_ASSERT__272[( callbacks[0] == func1)?1:-1] __attribute__((unused))
```

but I'm getting compilation error:

```
error: variably modified '__C_ASSERT__272' at file scope
```

Comment: And what *is* `C_ASSERT`? There's no such macro (which I assume it is) in standard C.

Comment: Please show a [MCVE]

Comment: Why do you *need* an assert?  You've declared the array `const`, so nothing but `func1` can ever be in that position.  If you're worried that someone will change the code incompatibly, then that's a job for your unit tests (and good comments to explain *why* `callbacks[0]` must be `func1`).

Comment: I have added the expansion of the C_ASSERT to the question. I need it in order to prevent a change by mistake (by someone else). The example in the question is naturally minimized than the real code.

Comment: I am voting to reopen. Selected duplicate is not accurate: `_Static_assert` would also not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Values of variables (`callbacks[0]` in this case) cannot be used in constant expressions in C. Not even if variable is declared `const`.

You have to do either runtime assertion or check, or add big comment next to array definition saying `/* func1 must be first! */`.